# Refreshing Spotify access_token

Tags: oauth-2.0, refresh, token, spotify

I'm trying to use the refresh_token to (obviously) refresh the Spotify access_token I have. The documentation gives this as an example curl statement:

`curl -H "Authorization: Basic ZjM4Zj...Y0MzE=" -d grant_type=refresh_token -d refresh_token=NgAagA...NUm_SHo https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token`

and here is my Python implemtation:

`payload = {
    'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
    'refresh_token': <REFRESH_TOKEN>
}
r = requests.post('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', data=payload,
                        headers={'Authorization': 'Basic <CLIENT_SECRET>'})`

In both cases I get back `{"error":"invalid_client"}`

I've tried passing my client_id and the client_secret in the post data but I always get back invalid_client. Someone here on SO said I need to pass in code, but code is a single use, very short lived object that has already been consumed/expired.

Any thoughts to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I can see is that you write:

```
headers={'Authorization': 'Basic <CLIENT_SECRET>'}
```

when it, using your notation, should be:

```
headers={'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode('<CLIENT_ID>:<CLIENT_SECRET>')}
```

However, that could be simplifed further since you are using requests. As described here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/ Just remove headers and replace it with auth instead:

```
auth=('<CLIENT_ID>', '<CLIENT_SECRET>')
```

However, I guess that this isn't what is actually wrong in your code either, since you somehow managed to get a refresh token which requires that you authorized successfully once before.

Comment: Bingo! The auth parameter to requests fixed it. I had an auth and refresh token because the initial OAuth calls are done in Javascript using the OAuth NPM while the refresh code is in Python. Thanks, @joon.

Answer (score 0):

```
spot = SpotifyOAuth(<CLIENT_ID>, <CLIENT_SECRET>, <REDIRECT_URL>)
access_token = spot.refresh_access_token(<SPOTIFY_REFRESH>)
print(access_token)
```

This worked for me

https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.13.0/#spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOAuth